# C# merge distinct items of 2 collections

Tags: c#, collections

I'm looking for a performant way to add distinct items of a second ICollection to an existing one. I'm using .NET 4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it:

```
list1.Union(list2).Distinct(aCustomComparer).ToList()
```

Comment: Isn't it redundant to use Distinct() after Union()?

Comment: Depends on the conditions of the union. By default, the Union() method will only deduplicate objects that are the same reference. Since Distinct is using a custom IEqualityComparer, it will actually do something more than the union. BUT, that IEqualityComparer can also be given to the Union directly to use as its deduper, so it's slightly redundant

Comment: `Union` uses default equality comparer, which, depending on the type, may or may not be a reference comparer. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx.  Further, as you mentioned, it is better to supply the custom comparer to the `Union` method and eliminate the `Distinct` call for readability and (maybe?) a slight performance gain.

Comment: What is "aCustomComparer"?

Answer (score 6):

As long as they're IEnumerable, you can use the go-to Linq answer:

```
var union = firstCollection.Union(secondCollection);
```

This will use the default equality comparison, which for most objects is referential equality. To change this, you can define an IEqualityComparer generic to the item type in your collection that will perform a more semantic comparison, and specify it as the second argument of the Union.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to add to your exisiting list would be:

```
list1.AddRange(list2.Distinct().Except(list1));
```

Comment: This is basically the operation behind Union(), BTW. the Except() iterator will basically call Any(x=>x==Current) on the passed list1 and return items from list2 where it's false.

Comment: Except union doesn't modify the original list, OP requested to 'add distinct items of a second ICollection to an existing one', Union returns a new collection.

Comment: My answer may not be what the OP wanted, but his question is ambiguous enough that it could be.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct answer to your question - since you didn't give much detail on the actual types of ICollection you have as input or need as output is the one given by KeithS

```
var union = firstCollection.Union(secondCollection);
```

This will return a distinct IEnumerable - if that is what you need then it is VERY fast.  I made a small test app (below) that ran the union method (MethodA) against a simple hashset method of deduplicating and returns a Hashset<>(MethodB).  The union method DESTROYS the hashset:

> MethodA: 1ms
>
> MethodB: 2827ms

However -- Having to convert that IEnumerable to some other type of collection such as List<> (like the version ADas posted) changes everything:

Simply adding .ToList() to MethodA

```
var union = firstCollection.Union(secondCollection).ToList();
```

Changes the results:

> MethodA: 3656ms
>
> MethodB: 2803ms

So - it seems more would need to be known about the specific case you are working with - and any solution you come up with should be tested - since a small (code) change can have HUGE impacts.

Below is the test I used to compare these methods - I'm sure it is a stupid way to test - but it seems to work :)

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ICollection<string> collectionA = new List<string>();
        ICollection<string> collectionB = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            string randomString = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            collectionA.Add(randomString);
            collectionA.Add(randomString);
            collectionB.Add(randomString);
            collectionB.Add(randomString);
        }
        Stopwatch testA = new Stopwatch();
        testA.Start();
        MethodA(collectionA, collectionB);
        testA.Stop();


        Stopwatch testB = new Stopwatch();
        testB.Start();
        MethodB(collectionA, collectionB);
        testB.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("MethodA: {0}ms", testA.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("MethodB: {0}ms", testB.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void MethodA(ICollection<string> collectionA, ICollection<string> collectionB)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var result = collectionA.Union(collectionB);
        }
    }

    private static void MethodB(ICollection<string> collectionA, ICollection<string> collectionB)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var result = new HashSet<string>(collectionA);
            foreach (string s in collectionB)
            {
                result.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to be clear; there is ALWAYS a more performant solution than Linq. However, for 99.9% of what you'd program in .NET to begin with (as opposed to a more native language which will blow any .NET implementation out of the water) Linq is fine on performance and usually the more readable and understandable implementation.

Comment: The reason MethodA is so much faster is because it doesn't enumerate the elements of the collection it returns, this is the reason calling ToList on it makes it so much slower.