# Linq Query to join overlapping ranges and construct a new continuous range

Tags: c#, linq

Hello fellows I have been trying to construct a Linq Query that finds overlapping ranges in records and constructs a new single range that will join both ranges.

```
public class students
{
    public string course { get; set; }
    public int idStart { get; set;}
    public int idEnd { get; set;}
}

var c1 = new students(){course = "c#", idStart = 1, idEnd = 25};
var j1 = new students(){course = "java",idStart = 50, idEnd = 60};
var c2 = new students(){"c#", 20, 36};
var j2 = new students(){"java", 40, 55};
var c3 = new students(){"c#", 70, 80};

var studentranges = new list<students>;

studentranges.Add(c1);
studentranges.Add(j1);
studentranges.Add(c2);
studentranges.Add(j2);
studentranges.Add(c3);
```

Now I need to reformat the List `studentranges` such that reulting output is

```
studentranges = list<"c#", 1, 36; "Java", 40, 60; "c#", 70, 80>
```

Although in this example I have used only 2 ranges of C# & Java. The query needs to be flexible for `N number of Courses and N number of Ranges`

**My Code to achieve this:**

```
var c_range = studentranges.Where(u => u.course == "c#")
                           .OrderBy(u => u.idStart)
                           .ToList();

//assuming c_least is bound to exist for simplicity
var c_least = c_range.first(); 

var c_next = c_range.Where( u=> u.idStart > c_least.idStart && u.idEnd >= c_least.idEnd)
                    .First();

//assuming c_next is not null
c_least.idEnd = c_next.idEnd;
```

How to recurs further?

Comment: Are you simple trying to join two lists?

Comment: I want to get the overlapping Ids to merge as one in a list.

Comment: I think your answer is `list1.Union(list2).Distinct(aCustomComparer).ToList()` See here for more info [C# merge distinct items of 2 collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993666/c-sharp-merge-distinct-items-of-2-collections)

Comment: When you tried, where did you get stuck? I think you shouldn't do this in LINQ. Foreach is much better at such problems.

Comment: @GertArnold I was trying to avoid Foreach and do this simply with Linq but it seems I have to go that way.

Comment: Your question is unreadable. You should reformat it to make it more clear.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I just edited my question. Let me know if you understand what I am trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the records by course with [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), build the overlapping records for each group, and combine all the new records into one list with [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var result =
    studentranges.GroupBy(s => s.course)
    .SelectMany(GetRangesForGroup)
    .ToList();
```

`GetRangesForGroup` uses the same basic approach that you attempted: order by `idStart` and find the next `idEnd`. Full code:

```
private static IEnumerable<Student> GetRangesForGroup(IGrouping<string, Student> group) {
    var studentEnumerator = group.OrderBy(s => s.idStart).GetEnumerator();

    // move to first record and initialize range variables
    studentEnumerator.MoveNext();
    var idStart = studentEnumerator.Current.idStart;
    var idEnd = studentEnumerator.Current.idEnd;

    // iterate remaining records
    while (studentEnumerator.MoveNext()) {
        if (studentEnumerator.Current.idStart <= idEnd) {
            // current range starts before previous end point -- it overlaps

            // use the farthest end point
            if (studentEnumerator.Current.idEnd > idEnd) {
                idEnd = studentEnumerator.Current.idEnd;
            }
        } else {
            // the current range is non-overlapping

            // output previous range
            yield return new Student() { course = group.Key, idStart = idStart, idEnd = idEnd };

            // reinitialize variables for next range
            idStart = studentEnumerator.Current.idStart;
            idEnd = studentEnumerator.Current.idEnd;
        }
    }

    // output final range
    yield return new Student() { course = group.Key, idStart = idStart, idEnd = idEnd };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for your input, please check if it works for more types and input.

```
public class Students
    {
        public Students(Course c, int start, int end)
        {
            MyCourse = c;
            idStart = start;
            idEnd = end;
        }
        //        public string course { get; set; }
        public int idStart { get; set; }
        public int idEnd { get; set; }
        public Course MyCourse { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Course { CSharp, Java }

    public class MiscTests
    {
        private List<Students> students;
        private List<Students> result;
        public MiscTests()
        {
            students = new List<Students>
            {
                new Students(Course.CSharp, 1, 25),
                new Students(Course.Java, 50, 60),
                new Students(Course.CSharp, 20, 36),
                new Students(Course.Java, 40, 55),
                new Students(Course.CSharp, 70, 80),
            };

            result = new List<Students>();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            students = students.OrderBy(s => s.idEnd).ThenBy(s=>s.MyCourse).ToList();
            foreach (var s in students)
            {
                var lastOne = result.LastOrDefault(r=>r.MyCourse == s.MyCourse);
                if (lastOne == null)
                {
                    result.Add(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    var last = result.Last();
                    if (lastOne.MyCourse == last.MyCourse)
                    {
                        lastOne.idEnd = Math.Max(s.idEnd, lastOne.idEnd);
                        lastOne.idStart = Math.Min(s.idStart, lastOne.idStart);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when adding a third overlapping range `{CSharp, 20, 81}` -- should result in a single CSharp range from 1 to 81.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar with dates and making sure they did not overlap.  I used Rectangles and the [Intersect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0.aspx) To determine if the dates overlapped.  I think you could do something similar to get your list.  For the ones that intersect you'd union those together.